# Error on travis-ci build "No Rakefile found"

Tags: r, travis-ci

One github repo builds fine on travis, while another with almost exactly the same .travis.yaml file does not build, and gives the error

```
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
```

I have seen some discussions about travis yaml files not dealing with tabs correctly, etc. but I have checked there are no tabs, only whitespaces.

I have noticed that the `config` line on the travis dashboard has an entry for the repo that builds correctly

[image: the one that works]

while the one that doesn't build is missing that line

[image: the one that doesn't work]

However, they have the same yaml file more or less, so I don't understand why it doesn't work the same way.

[The yaml for the repo that builds](https://github.com/ropensci/rgbif/blob/master/.travis.yml)

[And the one that doesn't build  (some comments are removed, but that doesn't make a difference, I checked):](https://github.com/ropensci/rplos/blob/master/.travis.yaml)

Comment: Here's the most recent build attempt for the repo that doesn't work: https://travis-ci.org/ropensci/rplos/builds/6254046

Comment: rake is the 'ruby make' - yous to let you know. There must be something fundamentally wrong. I do not see any of the commands appear.

Comment: Right, I'm aware of that. But I don't have any Ruby in my repo. I do have a Makefile, but no rakefile. The questions I have seen on this suggest that if there is an error in the .travis.yaml then the build uses system defaults, which I assume then looks for a rakefile - and there isn't one as I don't need one for the repo

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you should rename the file to `.travis.yml`.

Sometimes I see it [used in a right](https://github.com/ropensci/rgbif) way but [here](https://github.com/ropensci/rplos/tree/3b4c6aad392f5fd1cbf174f6911e8c39dbc2a3ca) it is misspelled. That is why it is not executed.

Comment: I would also like if they just printed: `no rake file found using default behaviour`